# Exception inside a foreach "waits" for the query to be completed

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

So I have a **foreach** (that runs in a different task, but it isn't important) that **iterates through few million records** and does things with them. When I want to cancel the task (with a cancellation token) and **throwing an exception** it looks like **the exception cant "break out" from the foreach** for a few minutes *(my idea was that maybe it can't while the query is running)*.

Here is the sample code:

```
        var query = GetNrrSelectQuery(_dbContext);
        try
        {
            StartShift();
            foreach (var item in query.Select(x => new Something(x, _anonymizer)))
            {
                if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    _dbContext.Dispose();
                    return;
                    //token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                }
                while (workArea.Jobs.Count > workArea.JobsQueueSize)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                }

                workArea.Jobs.Enqueue(new Job
                {
                    ReportToImport = item
                });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            WorkArea.ImportingState = ProcessState.CRASHED;
        }
```

The whole code has non interesting parts because of the master-worker pattern I'm using. As you can see in `if (token.IsCancellationRequested)` statement i have tried everithing that came into my mind but it's not really wants to working (with and without disposing the dbContext, throwing exception, or just return).
In case of simply throwing an exception by calling `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();` the debugger stops at that particular row. Hiting the F11 (debug step inside) nothing really happens for a few minutes, than it breaks out of the foreach and the `try-catch` block catches it.

Is there any suggestion how to brake the whole query processing?

Or I'm looking in a completely wrong direction?

Comment: `Thread.Sleep(100);` looks pretty suspicious. Also, I couldn't understand its reasoning.

Comment: There's no cancellation or master/worker here. The loop iterates over the results of a synchronous query. You *can't* cancel a database query, only the result iteration. What are you trying to do? There are probably other, better ways to do it. If you want a "worker", .NET has the Dataflow classes like ActionBlock<T> since 2012. Lately, Channels were added

Comment: If you want to throttle processing, use `await Task.Delay()` instead of freezing the *publisher* thread

Comment: `iterates through few million records and does things with them` in that case you should use the built-in dataflow or channel classes instead of inventing your own. Creating a processing pipeline isn't trivial, with concurrency, buffering, cancellation, error handling only a few of the potential problems

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It's the master-worker code's master part. As you can see it puts jobs in a queue and the workers are "fed" from it. But it doesn't really matter, it works just fine if it have to iterate through less records. I don't know what you ment by built in data-flow or channel classes. Can you recommend me a guide?